# Is there a way to modify a payload from Firebase Messaging before pushing to an iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I followed the steps and created an APNs key and is able to successfully send messages from the Firebase Messaging console. However I have several questions:

1. Is there a way to modify the content of the notification prior to releasing and alerting the device? (changing the string value in the messsage)
   I noticed how the code prints the messageID through `userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey]`. Is it possible to modify the payload by modifying `userInfo`?
2. Where exactly is the notification triggered and released to the device? For example, normally I use `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(_request: UNNotificationRequest)` to send a notification, but I can't identify the piece that does the action here.

```
//
//  TaiwanEEWApp.swift
//  TaiwanEEW
//
//  Created by Joe Lin on 2022/7/5.
//
//  This file contains the main entry point of the TaiwanEEW app.
//

import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import UserNotifications


@main
struct TaiwanEEWApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    ... scene related code ignored ...

}

// MARK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGOF8MqcAzY&ab_channel=DesignCode
// MARK: https://designcode.io/swiftui-advanced-handbook-push-notifications-part-2

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
}





extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
      let deviceToken:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        print("Device token: ", deviceToken) // This token can be used for testing notifications on FCM
    }
}





@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.banner, .badge, .sound]])
  }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

    }


  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID from userNotificationCenter didReceive: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }
    
}
```

Thank you so much!!